# My Spring CustomCollectionEditor implementation , not binding correctly

Tags: spring, data-binding

I have one select multiple in Spring:

```
<form:select  path="categoryProducts" id="destinationData" itemLabel="product.name" items="${categoryProducts}" itemValue="product.id" multiple="true" ondblclick="moveLeft(document.getElementById('destinationData'), document.getElementById('sourceData'))"  size="10" />
```

In my controller:

```
@InitBinder
  public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Set.class, "categoryProducts", new CustomCollectionEditor(Set.class)
    {
      @Override
      protected Object convertElement(Object element)
      {
          Product  p = new Product() ;
         try {

             Short id = new Short(String.valueOf(element));
              p = (Product) dataManager.find(Product.class, id);
             System.out.println(p.getId() + "\\" +p.getName());
             CategoryProduct c = new CategoryProduct ();
             c.setProduct(p);
             return c;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return p;
      }


    });
```

When I do submit, receive this log:

```
136 Product Name
105 Product Name
104 Product Name
211 Product Name
204 Product Name
409 Product Name
30/03/2011 07:32:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() para servlet cms lanzó excepción
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'category' on field 'categoryProducts': rejected value [136,105,104,211,204,409][type
```

The initiBinder is initialized, but throws exception in the end: (rejected value [136,105,104,211,204,409]) . 
Why?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the field "categoryProducts" of your command class (model attribute) is a

```
Set<String>
```

...or a Set of any class other than CategoryProduct. Try to change it to:

```
Set<CategoryProduct>
```